# Is there a way to stop the Microsoft Office from automatically turning on "Collapse the Ribbon"?

Tags: microsoft-office

When using a Windows 8 tablet, MS Office automatically turns on "Collapse the Ribbon".  And even when it's turned off by hand it gets automatically re-enabled.  This is truly annoying when the tablet is docked and connected to external monitors.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+f1 should do the trick.

Otherwise click the arrow-button on the upperright-corner next to the help icon.